# Set local gitlab server to ssl with self signed certification

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, https, gitlab

I have an Ubuntu server and installed gitlab. 
I reach the web interface from gitlab under the ubuntu IP or hostname.

Now i want to secure the site with ssl an created a certification file
based on the [link](https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Generate_Self-Signed_SSL_Certificate_with_OpenSSL).

Gitlab.rb config is:

```
 1. external_url = 'https://192.168.150.25/gitlab'
 2. nginx['enable'] = true
 3. nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
 4. gitlab_rails['registry_key_path'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/192.168.150.25.key"
 5. registry['rootcertbundle'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/192.168.150.25.crt"
```

I also installed the certificate on my local computer, from where i want to access the site.

"server" is the hostname of my ubuntu server.

When I enter the url:

- https://server/gitlab
- or https://192.168.150.25/gitlab

I get a failure:

> This is not a secure connection NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>
> Subject: 192.168.150.25
>
> Issuer: 192.168.150.25
>
> Expires on: 24.05.2023
>
> Current date: 25.05.2019

PEM encoded chain:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This server couldn't prove it was a server. Its security certificate does not specify alternative names. Possible reasons are a faulty configuration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Do u have any ideas to fix that?

King regards
duesmannr

Comment: When creating the certificate, you need to list the domain name as part of the _Subject Alternative Name_  X.509 extension. See https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7391219?hl=en